# Finding Coefficients involving Bessel Functions

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I have a differential equation: $x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} +(x^2-3)y=0$

I solved it and obtained:

> y[x] -> Sqrt[x] BesselJ[Sqrt[13]/2, x] C[1] + Sqrt[x] BesselY[Sqrt[13]/2, x] C[2]

Now I'm trying to find the value for `C[2]` and `C[1]` when `y[x]=0` at `x=0 and 1` at `x=1`.

I tried using simultaneous equations using the `Solve[ ]` function such as:

```
eq1 = Sqrt[x] BesselJ[Sqrt[13]/2, x] C[1] = 0
eq2 = Sqrt[x] BesselJ[Sqrt[13]/2, x] C[1] = 1
Solve[{eq1, eq2}, C[1]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `x=0` is a singular point for this. We can go about it less directly.

```
yx = 
 DSolveValue[{x^2*D[y[x], {x, 2}] + (x^2 - 3)*y[x] == 0, y[1] == 1}, 
  y[x], x]

(* Out[524]= 1/
 BesselY[Sqrt[13]/2, 
  1] (Sqrt[x] BesselY[Sqrt[13]/2, x] + 
   Sqrt[x] BesselJ[Sqrt[13]/2, x] BesselY[Sqrt[13]/2, 1] C[1] - 
   Sqrt[x] BesselJ[Sqrt[13]/2, 1] BesselY[Sqrt[13]/2, x] C[1]) *)
```

(Something like the above, maybe without the IC, should have been in the original post by the way. I really do not like to do unnecessary typing.)

So now we have one free parameter. We can get a general sort of solution for the case where `y[x]==x`, then extract an appropriate limit. First solve for when the expression in `x` is equal to `x`.

```
csmall = C[1] /. First[Solve[yx == x, C[1]]]

(* Out[543]= (Sqrt[x] BesselY[Sqrt[13]/2, 1] - BesselY[Sqrt[13]/2, x])/(
BesselJ[Sqrt[13]/2, x] BesselY[Sqrt[13]/2, 1] - 
 BesselJ[Sqrt[13]/2, 1] BesselY[Sqrt[13]/2, x]) *)
```

Now see if we can evaluate for `x==0`. Just plugging in will give an indeterminate form, so I take a limit instead.

```
c0 = Limit[csmall, x -> 0]

(* Out[544]= 1/BesselJ[Sqrt[13]/2, 1] *)
```

Now use that for the remaining constant.

```
yxComplete = yx /. C[1] -> c0

(* Out[547]= (Sqrt[x] BesselJ[Sqrt[13]/2, x])/BesselJ[Sqrt[13]/2, 1] *)
```

Comment: What about a value for C[2]? Thanks for the answer by the way

Comment: There is no `C[2]` (check `Out[524]`). I used one boundary condition so there was only one undetermined parameter.